# Reliable way to clone internal drive to external drive (Windows 8)?

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, command-line, usb

What is a reliable way to **clone an internal drive to an external drive** from an administrator account on Windows 8.

This involves several steps, some of which I know:

1) Use `icacls` and/or `takeown` to get all the proper permissions. **Is there a way to make sure you have read access to all files on the drive in one command?**

2) Make sure the external drive is mounted

3) Copy `C:\` to the drive, probably `D:\`. **What command should I use to copy them?** Should I use `copy` or is something else better? Should I use `xcopy`

This question relates to one I asked earlier here: [Make Microsoft Account a Local Account from the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/680329/make-microsoft-account-a-local-account-from-the-command-line/680407?noredirect=1#comment861804_680407)

Comment: Just use disk cloning software.

Comment: @gronostaj Is there no way to do it from the command line?

Comment: What the heck?  Why do you think you would need takeown/icacls to clone a system?    What exactly are you trying to do with this clone once you make it?  Copy/xcopy are not the tools you should be using at all.

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to **do it while the system isn't running**, i.e. using some sort of live disc.

The best one I can think of is [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

However, @MaXX suggests a pendrive with some linux on it - that would work too, but he omits the useful command: `dd`, which does a bit-for-bit copy.  Check the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) and do some research if you are interested in that.

If you tell us exactly what you want to accomplish - we can better tailor answers to you.  Without knowing more, the best solution will be to clone the entire drive - which *requires* the system to not be running.

Comment: Would Windows 8 running on a thumbdrive work? (As in, another Windows 8)

Comment: It could work, but if you want a bootable clone, for example, then your best bet is `dd` or `clonezilla`, I've never had much success with Windows cloners (at least consumer ones).